# Angular Cli global jquery: TS2304: Cannot find name '$'

Tags: jquery, angular, plugins, angular-cli, typescript-typings

When using jquery and jquery plugins globally. The ng compiler gives the following error:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
```

`vscode` successfully identifies the global `typings` as defined in `tsconfig`. Although the compiler throws the error, it still successfully loads the plugins globally. Is it possible to suppress this error?

**Solution 1:**
`import * as $ from 'jquery'`

This is not a viable solution because then the `typings` from the jquery plugins are then no longer available in `vscode`.

***Configuration***

**tsconfig:**

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types" // where jquery is also installed
    ],
```

**angular-cli:**

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"
  ],
```

Comment: Why are you using JQuery ?

Comment: `declare var $:JQueryStatic;`

Comment: @trichetriche because datatables requires it and is the only table component with the flexibility and features I need

Comment: @David where would you declare that? jquery typings already declares this, hence why the vscode finds it

Comment: Before the component where you use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `typeRoots` wasn't enough. Simply had to add the `types` for DataTables directly.